# dotnet test: List all tests and their test attributes/properties

Tags: c#, .net-core, nunit, vstest

When running `dotnet test my-tests.dll --list-tests` from command line, the utility outputs:

```
The following tests are available: 
    MyTest1
    MyTest2
```

However, these tests contain meta-data that I would also like displayed:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyTests 
{
    [Test, Property("some_key", "some_value1")]
    public void MyTest1() 
    { 
        // ...
    }

    [Test, Property("some_key", "some_value2")]
    public void MyTest2()
    { 
        // ...
    }
}
```

Is there any way that I can display the `Property` key/values while using the `--list-tests` flag in `dotnet test`?

Answer (score 0):

No -- according to the [dotnet test CLI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test), the `--list-tests` flag lists the discovered test names rather than running them.

If your goal is for your test names to reflect the fact that they are being run against certain values, `[TestCase]` may be where you want to look.

For example, the following:

```cs
public class Tests
{
    [TestCase("some_value1")]
    [TestCase("some_value2")]
    public void MyTestWithSomeKeyOf(string value)
    {
        Assert.Pass();
        // ...
    }
}
```

would produce the following output from `dotnet test --list-tests`:

```
PS C:\Users\SeanK\Repositories\2023_01_NunitRepro> dotnet test --list-tests
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  Repro -> C:\Users\SeanK\Repositories\2023_01_NunitRepro\Repro\bin\Debug\net7.0\Repro.dll
Test run for C:\Users\SeanK\Repositories\2023_01_NunitRepro\Repro\bin\Debug\net7.0\Repro.dll (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 17.4.0 (x64)
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The following Tests are available:
    MyTestWithSomeKeyOf("some_value1")
    MyTestWithSomeKeyOf("some_value2")
```